# File contains data in an unknown format. (m4a load from librosa)

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pytorch, librosa

So I am currently working on a DNN that takes in m4a files. I have ffmpeg, it creates a few batches and then dies on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/work/s163838/./main.py", line 126, in <module>
    
  File "/users/work/s163838/./main.py", line 96, in main
    print("e")
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1203, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1229, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 425, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
EOFError: Caught EOFError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 164, in load
    y, sr_native = __soundfile_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 195, in __soundfile_load
    context = sf.SoundFile(path)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1183, in _open
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1357, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'vox2/dev/aac/id08194/QnBYPze-x9A/00079.m4a': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/users/work/s163838/vox_celeb_loader.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    load(speaker2utt1, self.num_samples)
  File "/users/work/s163838/vox_celeb_loader.py", line 13, in load
    wav, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=16000)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 88, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 170, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 226, in __audioread_load
    reader = audioread.audio_open(path)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 111, in audio_open
    return BackendClass(path)
  File "/users/kdm/s163838/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/rawread.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._file = aifc.open(self._fh)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/aifc.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/aifc.py", line 314, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "/apl/tryton/python/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

I am using this  command

```
    wav, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=16000)
```

is it just a broken file? How do I skip such then? Or is it something about loading a m4a file even with ffmpeg and the desired output when tested on a single m4a file?

Comment: Did you check the file, whether it is broken or not?

Comment: When you transcode the file with `ffmpeg` on the command line (for example to `wav`), does `ffmpeg` show any errors? The EOFError seems to indicate that file was truncated.